# SSO with SAML step by step approach

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

how to do sso- can u please clarify me step by step process sso with SAML2.0 and using any identify provide (ping for net ..etc.

how can we send the initial request to the SSO page

Comment: what SSO solution technology do you use?